How does this simple (Class A?) MOSFET amplifier achieve linearity at 70% efficiency?
The KD1JV SSB/CW QRP Transceiver uses a IRF530A MOSFET as its final power amplifier stage, to produce 5 W at 70% efficiency:

The signal comes through the gate, and the IRF530A operates in common source configuration, with drain impedance entirely through a toroid inductor.
How does this produce a linear amplification (as required by SSB)? Putting an inductor between +V and the drain gives highly nonlinear results.
Furthermore, SSB should require a large conduction angle.  If the MOSFET is biased to Class A, how does it achieve 70% efficiency?

It isn't class-A (n<=50%) if efficiency is 70%. Maybe class-AB but wit 70% you are already in the realm of class-B/C. If T5 is connected as shown (4:1 instead of 1:4 ratio), it can not put out 5W @ 13.8V.

The lowpass filter also looks fishy so I checked. It has almost 6dB loss so not a usable 40m filter with the component values shown. The only thing spot on is the notch for the second harmonic. These are probably errors that happened when the original schematic was redrawn for publishing.

@Raonoke I agree with you on the transformer wiring error and estimation on class B. That LPF may be doing an additional impedance transformation to squeeze 5W out of that MOSFET. That LPF looks like a lower impedance on the left side.
